# Relationship between cell potential and applied potential in electrolysis

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

My question is about this problem, and I got the correct answer (which is 495g), but I am confused about the concept behind the correct approach:

"Calcium metal is obtained by the direct electrolysis of molten CaCl2. If a metallurgical electrolysis apparatus operates at 27.6 A and 1.2 V, what mass of calcium metal will it produce in 24 hours of operation?"

Basically, I did current * time to find the charge, then divided by (96485*2) since Ca has a 2+ charge. I got the correct answer. However, what I don't get is why I shouldn't take the standard cell potential into account. Specifically, why is it not correct to find the cell potential, then use the applied potential to find dG, and then divide that by the cell potential and the charge to find out the amount of Ca(s) that can be formed? Why is voltage not used in the problem at all? While the question is only asking about the formation of Ca(s), the reaction involves both the reduction of Ca2+ as well as the oxidation of Cl-, and I thought the oxidation step would need energy too, since these two half-reactions complete one redox reaction.

Comment: Relation of used energy and cell potential difference is much more complicated than relation of passed charge and molar amount. As analogy, you can solve linear algebraic equation by general formula for equation of the 3rd order, but why??

Comment: BTW standard redox potentials in molten salts are seldom known. Tabelated ones are for water solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess a follow-up question would then be, you said it's much more complicated than that and I think I understand your comment, so why is it conceptually wrong to do energy=current * applied voltage = -nFE0? (specifically, I found a number when I did I*V, then divided by -nFE0 to calculate the "number" of this redox reaction that has happened in 24 hours. I think there definitely is something wrong with this approach because it gave me ~130g yield, but I don't know where I did wrong.) Thank you again.

Comment: Rather Applied energy is integral of U.dq over time. But part of it is spent on Ohmic loses and part on transition potential differences. Such a big current means being miles away from an equilibrium state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current alone determines how much metal is deposited. Each charge carried replaces one valence electron, so, as you state, Ca++ requires two electrons to be transferred.

[How much metal should you get?](https://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/howtosolveit/Electrochem/Electrolysis.htm)  ~6.25 * 10<sup>18</sup> electrons = 1 Coulomb, or 1 Ampere-second. 96,485 coulombs = 1 Faraday, equivalent to 1 mole of a univalent metal.

Over-voltage, beyond cell potential, is changed to heat, but it does not electrolyze additional metal.